# Cannot read property 'data-ck-expando' of undefined when ngOnDestroy

Tags: angular8, webpack-4, ckeditor5, terser

ckeditor works just fine except that the ngOnDestroy handler crashes.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "8.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "1.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles": "11.1.4",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "12.4.0",
     ....
    "zone.js": "0.10.0"
  },
```

I am using webpack to minimizer with plugin "TerserPlugin".
the problem seems to come from

```
terserOptions: {
                    ecma: 6,
                    ie8: false,
                    toplevel: true,
                    module: true,
                    compress: {
                        dead_code: true,
                        warnings: false,
                        properties: true,
                        drop_debugger: true,
                        conditionals: true,
                        booleans: true,
                        loops: true,
                        unused: true,
                        toplevel: true,
                        if_return: true,
                        inline: true,
                        join_vars: true,
                        ecma: 6,
                        module: true,
                        toplevel: true
                    },
                    output: {
                        comments: false,
                        beautify: false,
                        indent_level: 2,
                        ecma: 6
                    },
                    mangle: {
                        module: true,
                        toplevel: true
                    }
                }
```

to tried, i changed zone.js in the polyfills.ts file in this way :

```
import 'core-js/proposals/reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone.js';
(window as any).__Zone_disable_toString = true;
require('../manifest.webapp');
```

But not working for me.

Here is the error :

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'data-ck-expando' of undefined
    at Si (4.83409f22a2c74d96c1fe.chunk.js:1)
    at Oa._getProxyEmitter (4.83409f22a2c74d96c1fe.chunk.js:1)
    at Oa.stopListening (4.83409f22a2c74d96c1fe.chunk.js:1)
    at Oa.destroy (4.83409f22a2c74d96c1fe.chunk.js:1)
    at Oa.destroy (4.83409f22a2c74d96c1fe.chunk.js:1)
    at ea.destroy (4.83409f22a2c74d96c1fe.chunk.js:1)
    at Ip.destroy (4.83409f22a2c74d96c1fe.chunk.js:1)
    at e.ngOnDestroy (main.83409f22a2c74d96c1fe.bundle.js:1)
    at ug (main.83409f22a2c74d96c1fe.bundle.js:1)
    at lg (main.83409f22a2c74d96c1fe.bundle.js:1)
```

Answer (score 2):

In **polyfills.ts** change this line:

import 'zone.js/dist/zone'; // Included with Angular CLI.

to

import 'zone.js/dist/zone.js'; // Included with Angular CLI.

Comment: I have already tested this modification but the problem will come from webpack with the minimizer

Answer (score 1):

You need turn off module property. Module (default false) -- Pass true when compressing an ES6 module. Strict mode is implied and the toplevel option as well. Documentation: https://github.com/terser/terser#compress-options

```
terserOptions: {
  compress: {
    module: false // here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

delete all the code in polyfill.ts and add below code

```
 import 'zone.js/dist/zone.js';  // Included with Angular CLI.
 (window as any).__Zone_disable_toString = true;
```

This should resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Andrew's answer was what did the trick for me. I'm using ckfinder with a new funcionality to insert raw html code in the editor. I tried to update the zone.js version to 0.10.0, tried to modify the file  polyfills.ts too, but it dind't work.

Just turn the module property to false in the following file: webpack.js

The structure is as follow:

```
terserOptions: {
  compress: {
    module: false 
  }
}
```

Ps.: I can't comment yet since I don't have enough points :(